# Dúvida Select MVC .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo um index, para trazer o funcionário e a classificação que ele está, porém se eu faço assim, ele me aparece o id da classificação, e não o nome:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Funcionario)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Nome</td>
            <td>@item.ClassificacaoID</td>
            <td align="right">
                <a  asp-action="Editar" asp-route-id="@item.Id" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                <a asp-action="Detalhe" asp-route-id="@item.Id" title="Visualizar"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                <a  asp-action="Excluir" asp-route-id="@item.Id"title="Excluir"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

No select está assim:

```
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = new IndexViewModel();
        model.Mensagem = "Carregando dados";
        model.Funcionario = await db.Funcionarios.OrderBy(f => f.Nome).ToArrayAsync();
        return View(model); 
    }
```

Como posso trazer o funcionário, e a descrição da classificação do mesmo ?

Comment: Mas você ta usando o item.ClassificacaoID, então vai printar o ID, você precisa de uma propriedade do tipo Classificacao dentro da viewmodel ou do funcionário, e aí sim, usar um item.Classificacao.Descricacao

Comment: Eu tenho, e faço isso, porém ele me retorna o seguinte erro NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Lembrando que eu fiz assim: <td>@item.Classificacoes.Descricao</td>

Comment: Você ta usando Entity? Se sim, deu o include?

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado rs.